# Creating Pie chart in python from dataframes

Tags: python, pie-chart

I am just trying to create 2 pie charts, one based on SalesQuantity and one based on ProfitPerBottle. My code and tables are shown below

```
HenSalePur["ProfitPerBottle"] = HenSalePur['SalesPrice'] - HenSalePur['PurchasePrice']
DonJSalePur["ProfitPerBottle"] = DonJSalePur['SalesPrice'] - DonJSalePur['PurchasePrice']
HenSalePur["TotalProfit"] = HenSalePur['ProfitPerBottle'] * HenSalePur['SalesQuantity']
DonJSalePur["TotalProfit"] = DonJSalePur['ProfitPerBottle'] * DonJSalePur['SalesQuantity']

DonJVolumeGrouped = DonJSalePur.groupby('Size').agg('sum')
print(DonJVolumeGrouped)
```

[Graph for different bottles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwP9R.png)

[Graph sorted by volume used for pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKzBz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your tabular data loaded into a **pandas** **DataFrame**, you can use the code below to retrieve the required plots:

```
plot_salesquantity = DonJVolumeGrouped.plot.pie(y='SalesQuantity')
plot_profitperbottle = DonJVolumeGrouped.plot.pie(y='ProfitPerBottle')
```